# hack insertion sort to make it work differently

Tags: algorithm, function, hash

Below is the original pseudocode for Insertion Sort:

```
function INSERTIONSORT(A[0..n−1])
for i←1 to n−1 do 
    j←i−1 
    while j≥0 and A[j+1]<A[j] do 
          SWAP(A[j+1],A[j]) 
          j←j−1
```

A company is using Insertion Sort inside one of their products. You are a cybersecurity expert that was hired by this company to assess any security flaws with their code. After a few tries, you managed to attack their Insertion Sort code and modify it in the following way (shown in bold blue colour in the pseudocode below):

```
function INSERTIONSORT(A[0..n−1])
         for i←1 to n−1 do
         j←i−1 
         while j≥0 and HASH(A,j+1) < HASH(A,j) do 
               SWAP(A[j+1],A[j])
               j←j−1
```

In other words, instead of indexing the array as A[j] and A[j+1]inside the “while” condition, you now have a hash function that takes the array and a index as the arguments and return an integer.  Your job is to implement specific hash functions that will cause the algorithm to malfunction in different ways.

- Implement a hash function that causes Insertion Sort to keep the original array unchanged. Explain why your solution works.
- Implement a hash function that causes Insertion Sort to always run in the worst case complexity,  even if the resulting array does not end up getting sorted.   Explain why your solution works.
- Implement a hash function that causes Insertion Sort to sort the array in reverse.  Explain why your solution works.

I have no clue to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since this clearly is homework, I'll restrict this answer to a hint:
For the first two of those cases, think about an array such that the original insertion-sort implementation shows the requested behavior (let's call that array `A'`). Now you can look for a function `HASH`, such that `HASH(A, j + 1) < HASH(A, j)` shows the exact same behavior as `A'[j + 1] < A'[j]`. If you manage to solve the first two, the last one should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Hi, I think a and b is hash(A,j）=j and hash(A,j)=-j, but i do not know what c's answer is.